# Can you train voice to text to recognize only your voice in android?

Tags: java, android, voice-recognition

I am creating an app and I would like to recognize the voice of the user, not around voices. Is this possible?

Part of code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE,Locale.getDefault());
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "SAY SOMETHING");

    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, ""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: It is not possible with this code, you'll have to use a custom library.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev are you aware of such a library?

Comment: Something like https://github.com/ALIZE-Speaker-Recognition/android-alize